# JavaScript y swiper slider

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hola Amigos de StackOverflow,

Se me ha planteado un problema demasiado complejo para mí. Tengo una página que utilizan el plugin de swiper slider. Dentro de los sliders tengo un botón que visualiza una capa hermana del contenedor, con la clase on.

Me han pedido, que cuando el slider cambie de imagen, la capa hermana se deje de visualizar. No puedo dejar el código exacto pero sí un ejemplo que os dejo abajo.

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/css/swiper.css">
<div class="interactive-slider">
 <div class="image-interactive">
  <div class="swiper-container swiper-container-horizontal" style="cursor: grab;">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper" style="transform: translate3d(-2340px, 0px, 0px); transition-duration: 0ms;">
      <div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-duplicate swiper-slide-duplicate-next" data-swiper-slide-index="2" style="width: 1170px;">     
       <a href="#ancla-content-interactive" class="show-first-interactive link-mas-info-banner" onclick="MuestraLegal(2)">Mas información</a>                                         
          <picture>
            <source srcset="" media="(max-width: 442px)">
            <source srcset="" media="(max-width: 788px)">
            <img src="" alt="">
          </picture>                                
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-prev" data-swiper-slide-index="0" style="width: 1170px;">                                       
           <picture>
            <source srcset="" media="(max-width: 442px)">
            <source srcset="" media="(max-width: 788px)">
             <img src="" alt="Renault Megane para empresas">
          </picture>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-active" data-swiper-slide-index="1" style="width: 1170px;">     
          <a href="#ancla-content-interactive" class="show-first-interactive link-mas-info-banner" onclick="MuestraLegal(1)">Mas información</a>
          <picture>
            <source srcset="" media="(max-width: 442px)">
            <source srcset="" media="(max-width: 788px)">
            <img src="" alt="">
          </picture>                                
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-next" data-swiper-slide-index="2" style="width: 1170px;">     
          <a href="#ancla-content-interactive" class="show-first-interactive link-mas-info-banner" onclick="MuestraLegal(2)">Mas información</a>                                         
          <picture>
            <source srcset="" media="(max-width: 442px)">
            <source srcset="" media="(max-width: 788px)">
            <img src="" alt="">
          </picture>                                
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-slide swiper-slide-duplicate swiper-slide-duplicate-prev" data-swiper-slide-index="0" style="width: 1170px;">                                    
          <picture>
            <source srcset="" media="(max-width: 442px)">
            <source srcset="" media="(max-width: 788px)">
            <img src="" alt="">
          </picture>
          </div></div>
          <span class="swiper-notification" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="swiper-pagination swiper-pagination-clickable swiper-pagination-bullets">
          <span class="swiper-pagination-bullet" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-label="Go to slide 1"></span>
          <span class="swiper-pagination-bullet swiper-pagination-bullet-active" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-label="Go to slide 2"></span>
          <span class="swiper-pagination-bullet" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-label="Go to slide 3"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>

<!--La capa hermana que se visualiza cuando haces click en el botón, cerrar oculta la capa. -->

<div class="content-interactive">
  <div class="first-interactive on">
    <a>X CERRAR</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

¿Alguien puede darme alguna pista?

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el enlace al plugin?

Comment: Hola Pablo! Gracias Por contestar. Sí. Aquí lo dejo! https://swiperjs.com/